# Centering a big table

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I have two problems with this table: it doesn't appear centered in the text (probably it's too large, but i can't make it smaller), and it shows two lines at its bottom. 
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
..
\end{table} doesn't work

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | @{}m{0pt}@{}}

\cline{2-5}

 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Probe} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Probe} \\[0.5cm]

\cline{2-5}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} \\[0.5cm]

\hline
a   & 5,0441    &1,9797 &4,6986 &2,9247   &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
b       &1,0364 &1,0047 &-1,2025    &-0,9834 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
c   & 0,5283    &0,0717 &0,1125 &0,3644 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
d   & 0,2361    &0,1967 &-0,1241    &-0,3231 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
e   & 0,0241    &-0,0014    &0,0028 &0,0286 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
f       & 0,0924    &-0,0234    &-0,1167    &-0,1930 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
\label{tab:1}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: remove the `\label{tab:1}` at the end which is in the wrong place and making the spurious last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the spurious `\label` that was generating an extra row at the end, and hid the width of the table, so it centres, not clear why it has to be so wide, perhaps it is just the small example, but with the data shown it would be a lot more readable without all the extra space and without the vertical lines. (see the `booktabs` package)

but:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\makebox[0pt]{%
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | @{}m{0pt}@{}}

\cline{2-5}

 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Probe} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Probe} \\[0.4cm]

\cline{2-5}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} & \multicolumn{1}{c|} {Pump} \\[0.4cm]

\hline
a   & 5,0441    &1,9797 &4,6986 &2,9247   &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
b       &1,0364 &1,0047 &-1,2025    &-0,9834 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
c   & 0,5283    &0,0717 &0,1125 &0,3644 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
d   & 0,2361    &0,1967 &-0,1241    &-0,3231 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
e   & 0,0241    &-0,0014    &0,0028 &0,0286 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
f       & 0,0924    &-0,0234    &-0,1167    &-0,1930 &\\[0.4cm]

\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have five one inch wide columns, plus the intercolumn spaces and the rules, which makes for 72.27pt times 5 plus 6pt times 10 plus 0.4 times 6, that is, 423.75pt; the standard text width is 345pt.

Indeed, compiling your example file shows the warning

```
Overfull \hbox (78.74991pt too wide)
```

The small difference is due to rounding to scaled points, but 0.00009pt is 6 scaled points (much less than the wavelength of visible light).

Framing table entries as if they were in a worksheet is not good typography, using too wide columns makes for hard reading.

You get a much finer table by using `booktabs` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Probe} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Probe} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 & {Pump} & {Pump} & {Pump} & {Pump} \\
\midrule
a   & 5,0441 &  1,9797 &  4,6986 &  2,9247 \\
b   & 1,0364 &  1,0047 & -1,2025 & -0,9834 \\
c   & 0,5283 &  0,0717 &  0,1125 &  0,3644 \\
d   & 0,2361 &  0,1967 & -0,1241 & -0,3231 \\
e   & 0,0241 & -0,0014 &  0,0028 &  0,0286 \\
f   & 0,0924 & -0,0234 & -0,1167 & -0,1930 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A comparison with your original is illuminating:

[image]

Vertical rules hinder legibility and white space doesn't ease it either.

In any case a table should be as wide as it should be. ;-) Widening the intercolumn spacing just for making it bigger is a sure recipe for making the table worse.

One comment about `S` columns: a cell containing braced contents is considered a header (or non numeric data anyway) and centered in the available space, so the header is simply input as `{Pump}`. A `\midrule` separates the top part from the data.

Note that minus signs are the real thing and not hyphens. You can change the output to have a decimal point instead of a comma by just removing the `\sisetup` line in the preamble.

Finally, `\label` pertains to the table caption; a `table` environment can indeed have more than one `tabular` and a caption for each one, if you want to keep them together. The `\label` must go in the argument of `\caption` or after it.